# PWM low frequency generation low current draw

Tags: pcb-design

I'm a mechanical engineer with the work assignment to develop a low current draw PCB to control a servo mechanism. The device must work on two 9 volt batteries in series (the device must deliver an 18 volt maximum amplitude signal) and remain operable for up to 72 hours of continuous operation, which gives a roughly estimated allowable current draw of (500 mA hrs/72) = 6.94 mA at best.

I'm struggling with the simple feasibility of this project, as 6.94 mA isn't enough to power my Arduino Nano on sleep mode. I can negotiate the operation down to 48 hours of operation, which is 10.4 mA allowable draw (I'm highly aware that 9 Volts do not really have 500 mA of effective power, it's highly dependent on conditions).

Furthermore, the servos I'm trying to control requires both variable duty cycle and variable frequency (based on the brand of servo), and the frequencies vary from 100 Hz to 1500 Hz, which from what I've seen is an extremely slow frequency compared to most PWM applications where desired frequency is in the tens of kHz range or higher.

Can anyone tell me

A) is this possible under any circumstances? 
B)is there a better battery out there that doesn't require complex recharging circuits like a Lipo often does? 
C) Could I use a LM555 Timer to generate this circuit; a bit of simple calculation shows that the capacitor/resistor combination to be used in astable mode for this chip (according to datasheet) would require a very beefy resistor and capacitor? 
D) Is there a low current draw arduino compatible microcontroller that would make this simpler.? I am also somewhat familiar with PIC devices.

Comment: Certainly. There are other micros that can sleep on less than a microamp.

Comment: This question is pretty vague. A) Yes. B) What do you mean by "better" and "complex"? C) Possibly, more specifications needed. D) Yes.

Comment: what output currents must you provide? what loads to be driven?

Comment: When you say "frequencies vary" do you mean that different servos have a different fixed frequency or that the frequency for a given servo must be variable? What are your allowable tolerances on frequency and duty factor?

Comment: The PCB must be compatible with multiple types of servos, each with a different fixed PWM frequency input. The PWM signal is logic only, usually just 10 micro amps is needed to drive a pull up resistor.

Comment: Again, what are your allowable tolerances on frequency and duty factor?

Comment: 0 to 100% duty cycle at 0 to 100 hz

Comment: "the device must deliver an 18 volt maximum amplitude signal... the servos I'm trying to control requires both variable duty cycle and variable frequency (based on the brand of servo), and the frequencies vary from 100 Hz to 1500 Hz" - can you provide a datasheet or link to any of these servos?

Answer (score 0):

> The device must work on two 9 volt batteries in series... 6.94 mA
>   isn't enough to power my Arduino Nano on sleep mode.

The Arduino Nano has a linear regulator so powering it directly from 18V is extremely inefficient and a bit dangerous (*absolute maximum* input voltage of the LM1117 is 20V). With 18V in and 5V out the on-board regulator drops 13V so it is only 28% efficient, wasting 72% of the battery power.

However if you use an external switching regulator (aka 'DC/DC converter') it will increase output current as it reduces voltage, typically with 70~90% efficiency. For example, [this buck converter module](https://www.ebay.com/itm/Mini-DC-DC-4V-12-24V-To-5V-3A-Adjustable-Step-Down-Power-Module-Buck-Converter/272694825804?hash=item3f7de0d34c:g:o1YAAOSw8PJcP-e7) converts 18V at 3.75mA to 5V at 10.6mA (measured values), corresponding to an efficiency of 77%.

But you may be able to do even better than this. The Nano has a USB interface chip which draws several mA. The [Pro Mini](https://www.ebay.com/itm/1-2-3PC-Arduino-Pro-Mini-Atmega328-5V-16M-Replace-ATmega128-Compatible-Nano/273877140525?hash=item3fc459842d:m:mqhILyRoCIftci-U_p6C_kQ) has no USB so you have to program it with a TTL-USB adapter cable, but the current draw is much lower. The 5V (16MHz) version only draws 3.2mA in sleep mode, but most of this current is consumed by the power LED and 5V regulator. If you remove them it only draws 0.06mA in sleep - less than the quiescent current draw of the DC/DC converter above (~0.28mA).

With more advanced tricks such as switching to the 128kHz internal oscillator or using a 32.678kHz crystal it could go even lower, then the only problem is finding a regulator with low enough quiescent current to make it worthwhile. In one project I used the [LP2950](http://www.ti.com/product/LP2950) which has a quiescent current draw of 0.075mA, low enough to be insignificant in my application.